# Rollback not triggered on exception

Tags: transactions, ejb, java-ee-7, jta

I have been busting my head the last couple of days. I have a MDB which has a method level `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)`. The method that gets called in a different EJB is marked as `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` thus suspending the MDB transaction. When an exception is thrown in the new transaction it does not rollback and commits my changes to the databsse. I did mark my checked exception with `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)` here is the code example

```
public class MDB implements MessageListener {

    @EJB
    Foo foo;
    @Inject
    ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        //message gets unmarshalled here
        try {
            foo.makeChanges(unmarshalledMessage)
        } catch (MyException ex) {
            exceptionHandler.handleException(ex);
        }
    }
}

@Stateless
public class Foo {

    @EJB
    DatabaseDao databaseDao;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void makeChanges(String unmarshalledMessage) throws MyException {
        //Some logic to handle message
        try (Connection conn = databaseDao.getConnection()) {
            for (ManipulatedString string : listOfManipulatedString) {
                try {
                    databaseDao.makeChanges(manipulatedString);
                    //RuntimeException thrown 
                } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                    throw new MyException(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

@ApplicationException(rollback = true)
public class MyException extends Exception {
    public MyException() {
        super();
    }

    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }


    public MyException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public MyException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that I only want the second transaction to roll back (The transaction created in the Foo class) and not the first transaction (The transaction in the MDB). I explicitly threw an exception for negative testing.

I have records that gets send to the database one by one, hence the `for`. On the third record it fails (My doing) and it should rollback and not commit anything but for some reason it commits the previous . Do you have any idea why

I only use Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. I was not using the correct JDBC driver. I was using oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver with no global transactions. I switched to oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource and it fixed the problem.

I saw that my transactions were created and the Foo transaction does roll back as expected. I used the weblogic monitoring tool to determine this. I then realized it had something to do with my JDBC and its transactionality.